# SSO using SAML - Error using Heroku App setting Up SAML

Tags: security, single-sign-on, authentication, saml, heroku

I am trying to test out by setting up SSO in my trailhead org. Following these steps - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_service_provider_configuration.htm&type=5

I setup SSO like this:

[image]

I used https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/Home.action to help with setting up an IDP. AND used this https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/SamlIdpResponseAndTargetPosterForm.action to do the login after setting up SSO in SF.

The SAML assertion response is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml1p:Response xmlns:saml1p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" IssueInstant="2023-11-21T20:09:20.229Z" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" Recipient="https://cunning-impala-k2qke1-dev-ed.trailblaze.my.salesforce.com" ResponseID="_4aac2d37-1591ff76">
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_4aac2d37-1591ff76">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>pNRVYUBQPfBPfOQ0kR6FCe8pfkM=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>azD+J85W6BoULPi6bFmhWhUPJb1J6f8HI7Y9662wHjQOyuaamerMdg==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIID0zCCA5GgAwIBAgIEF/uFITALBgcqhkjOOAQDBQAwgboxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQI
EwJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzESMBAGA1UEChMJQXhpb20gU1NPMVEwTwYDVQQL
E0hGT1IgREVNT05TVFJBVElPTiBQVVJQT1NFUyBPTkxZLiBETyBOT1QgVVNFIEZPUiBQUk9EVUNU
SU9OIEVOVklST05NRU5UUy4xHzAdBgNVBAMTFkF4aW9tIERlbW8gQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwHhcNMTQw
NjIwMDQzMDI3WhcNNDExMTA1MDQzMDI3WjCBujELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYw
FAYDVQQHEw1TYW4gRnJhbmNpc2NvMRIwEAYDVQQKEwlBeGlvbSBTU08xUTBPBgNVBAsTSEZPUiBE
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml1p:Status>
        <saml1p:StatusCode Value="saml1p:Success"/>
    </saml1p:Status>
    <saml1:Assertion xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" AssertionID="_7dad73d9-13acc6a0" IssueInstant="2023-11-21T20:09:20.229Z" Issuer="Heroku" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1">
        <saml1:Conditions NotBefore="2023-11-21T20:09:20.229Z" NotOnOrAfter="2023-11-21T20:10:20.229Z">
            <saml1:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                <saml1:Audience>https://saml.salesforce.com</saml1:Audience>
            </saml1:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
        </saml1:Conditions>
        <saml1:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2023-11-21T20:09:20.229Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified">
            <saml1:Subject>
                <saml1:NameIdentifier>XYZ@cunning-impala-k2qke1.com</saml1:NameIdentifier>
                <saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
                    <saml1:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml1:ConfirmationMethod>
                </saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml1:Subject>
        </saml1:AuthenticationStatement>
    </saml1:Assertion>
</saml1p:Response>
```

This what Axiom IDP login Page look like:

[image]

When I click login I get this screen:

[image]

When I used SAMPL validator I get this screen:

[image]

Does it mean that SAML generated with https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/SamlIdpHome.action is in 1.1 version and can't be used? Can I not setup and test SSO like this?ANything I am missing?

Is there any other suggestion how I can create and test a sample SSO? If I can use another IDP that is public then pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I see some glaring mistakes.

1. **Entity ID** should be the domain name of your Salesforce instance (which should be the same name as your Login URL in your first screenshot)
2. **Issuer** should not be Heroku think it should be (https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com
3. Why are you using Username rather than Federation ID? and HTTP POST rather than HTTP Redirect?

You can reference this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-i-configured-single-sign-on-salesforce-users-anna-szabo-mba/) for this SSO testing